# cannot delete file after Isolate.kill: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a simple windows app, where I encrypt a file in a dart isolate. During the process, the user can cancel the operation, and when that happened, I'll kill the isolate and do some cleanup, e.g, delete the partially processed file.

I got a "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" when trying to delete the partially written file.

I tried the following

- Delete the file right after `Isolate.kill`
- Delete the file in on [exit handler](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-isolate/Isolate/addOnExitListener.html)

Both results in the same "File being used by process" error.

My question is, is there any way to wait for the isolate to completely killed (all file handles are released), so I can safely delete them? Or if it's possible to get notifed in the code running in isolate, so that I can stop and release the file handle...

Comment: post your isolate `entryPoint` code

Comment: What is the value of the isolate's `terminateCapability` property?

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve this? Thank you.